# Brute Force out of memory space

Tags: java, brute-force

I'm busy creating a brute force TSP algorithm, the program currently works and calculates the shortest possible route I input. Sadly the maximum amount of nodes I can use is 10, this is because whenever I go higher I get: "Java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space". I've already been trying to optimize the code but the result has been negligible. How can I further optimize my code so I can use more nodes while running my algorithm?

This is my code:

```
import com.sybrand.TSP.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BruteForce extends TSP_Algorithm {

    private ArrayList<Coordinate> sortedCoords = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Coordinate> shortestRoute;

    public BruteForce(ArrayList<Coordinate> coords) {
        sortedCoords.addAll(coords);
        permutation(sortedCoords);
    }

    public void permutation(ArrayList<Coordinate> nums) {
        List<List<Coordinate>> accum = new ArrayList<>();
        permutation(accum, Collections.emptyList(), nums);
        float shortestDistance = 0.0f;
        for (List<Coordinate> routeOption: accum) {
            Path calcDistance = new Path((ArrayList<Coordinate>) routeOption);
            if (shortestDistance == 0.0f || calcDistance.getDistance() < shortestDistance) {
                shortestDistance = calcDistance.getDistance();
                this.shortestRoute = (ArrayList<Coordinate>) routeOption;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void permutation(List<List<Coordinate>> accum, List<Coordinate> prefix, List<Coordinate> nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        if (n == 0) {
            accum.add(prefix);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                List<Coordinate> newPrefix = new ArrayList<>(prefix);
                newPrefix.add(nums.get(i));
                List<Coordinate> numsLeft = new ArrayList<>(nums);
                numsLeft.remove(i);
                permutation(accum, newPrefix, numsLeft);
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Coordinate> getSortedCoordinates() {
        return shortestRoute;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instead of creating the list and then checking each permutation why don't you check them as you create them and keep track of only the shortest one. It's still brute-forceing, but should drop the memory usage significantly.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the idea. I've changed it so it checks it on the go, and it, as you predicted, went down from 4.5gb of ram to 250mb. It works now :) Thanks!